# Conditional Precaching in Workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

There are cases where an application might need a relatively large resource as a strict requirement, but only in certain cases that are not easily detectable from a service worker. For example:

- Safari has a prefixed and non-conforming implementation of the Web Audio API. I found a great shim, but it's over 300kb. It's critical for the web app to function in Safari but unnecessary in other browsers.
- Some media are available in multiple formats that may not always be supported. Video is typically too large to precache and has problems with range requests, but it could apply to WebP images or short audio files (e.g. Opus vs. AAC). If you include all formats in the precache manifest, by default it will download all of them.

One approach would be to manually exclude certain files from the precache manifest and then to conditionally load those files from the scripts on the main thread to be stored in the runtime cache. But then those files are not precached - they're only loaded after the new version activates, by which point you may no longer be online.

Is there a solution that allows the following?:

- Have the service worker send a message to the main thread with the URL of a "test" script that checks the various conditions.
- Load and run that script on the main thread and send the service worker the list of required conditional assets
- Add those assets to the precache manifest to be diff'ed against the previous version and downloaded as necessary
- The service worker should not switch over to the new version until all precached assets are loaded, including the conditional ones.

Comment: It's an important use case—I'd recommend moving the discussion to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/155 which has some context about potential approaches.

Comment: Thanks! The contrib guide suggested I try this first, and I hadn't seen that issue. But I'll paste it in there too.

Comment: @JeffPosnick Does this mean that what I'm trying to accomplish won't be possible without changes to workbox?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with i18n files. I don't want my users to precache all strings for all available languages.

Some context for my setup. I'm using the `injectManifest` approach for vite. The webpack plugin should expose the same config options for this.

Language files in my case have this shape in the build dir:

```
assets/messages.XXXX.js
```

So the first step was to tell the `injectManifest` config to ignore these files:

```
injectManifest: {
  globIgnores: ["**/node_modules/**/*", "assets/messages.*.js"],
}
```

The second step was going into the `sw.js` file and tell workbox that all scripts that aren't precached should be requested via the `CacheFirst` strategy. (i.e. first attempt to load it from the cache, if not present, load it from the network and put it into the cache).

So here's the adapted part of the `sw.js`:

```js
/* ... */
import {registerRoute, NavigationRoute, Route} from "workbox-routing";
import {CacheFirst} from "workbox-strategies";

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Handle non-pre-cached scripts
const scriptsRoute = new Route(
  ({request}) => {
    return request.destination === "script";
  },
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: "scripts",
  })
);

cleanupOutdatedCaches();

registerRoute(new NavigationRoute(createHandlerBoundToURL("index.html")));
registerRoute(scriptsRoute);
/* ... */
```